# Syntax Error occurred when try to build the react-native android application in genymotion

Tags: react-native

I create an android application using react-native when I try to load that application into Genymotion it shows an error as
399/400Error while persisting cache: SyntaxError /home/samantha/AwesomeProject/index.android.js: "React" is read-only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I done a mistake in my index.android.js

```
render() {
    var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
    var React = require("react-native");
    var Image = React.Image;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
            <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
            <Image source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
                   style={style.thumbnail}/>
            <View style={style.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={style.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
                <Text style={style.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

this is my react render() function this one works fine
previously I wrote as

```
var React = require("react-native");
var Image = React.Image;
render() {
    var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
            <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
            <Image source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
                   style={style.thumbnail}/>
            <View style={style.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={style.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
                <Text style={style.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
       );
    }
```

because of that it is showed as "React" is read-only